# Stuck trying to advance to the next loop in GUI class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm a long time observer, and first time poster. So forgive me if I seem to skip over some typical guidelines.

Posted below is a link to my GUI class, where I display different "screens"/JPanels in my client program. The client keeps track of these screens by referencing a state variable, which is documented at the top of the class.

Upon launching the client, the GUI builds the JFrame, then starts attaching things to it. First up is a splash screen, then after a short time it moves on to displaying a menu. This part should be clear in the code. The problem I'm experiencing occurs when a menu item component is clicked on. The GUI properly removes the menu from the window, however it doesn't move on to displaying the login screen. Both the menu and, login screens are attached in a similar fashion. Despite my best efforts to debug the code by printing messages at each step, I can't seem to figure out why after changing the state to "3", the GUI doesn't advance into the "Login" phase of the loop and, display the login screen.

http://pastebin.com/xWDpjD14

Also, I should note, the state is being changed by a Mouse Listener class attached to each menu item of the menu screen. I've already debug'd this part. I just can't figure out why the loops aren't working as expected.

Sorry I don't have a SCCE(sp?) to attach, It's my first post, and I'm not quite familiar with the sites posting options yet.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Also, have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). You seem to be trying to approach this problem from the point of view of a console/procedural style program, which is NOT how GUI's work, GUI's are event driven environments, that is, something happens and you  respond to it, all those loops with in loops is a really bad idea

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion regarding CardLayout, complacency seems to have made things harder then they needed to be here. As I recently found my way around GridBagLayout, I failed to recognize the better top level solution. Converting my GUI to an event driven model won't be time efficient, but atleast things should work better. Despite not providing a straightforward answer, I think the suggestions you provided will solve the problem, without hacking things together.

Comment: *" but atleast things should work better"* - Not really, you're basically violating the single thread rules of the API, violating the thread safety rules of the API and basically screwing the whole API over, rather the working with the API the way it was designed to. *"... without hacking things together* - You've already done that :P

Comment: Lol, well I was trying to say "it will be better". Which, after rewriting the GUI to use CardLayout at the top level, works as expected. My login screen is finally showing up, and I got rid of about half the code I had packed in there. This is the revised class: http://pastebin.com/NR3MRGTk. I left the runnable code in there because I'm still attached to it emotionally :D. Thanks MadProgrammer.